# why does directx 9 lack of resources? c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx-9

directx 9 is most library i have found that doesn't have any free tutorials or resources.
why is that?

Comment: DX9 has a huge number of tutorials compared to a lot of libraries. But what exactly do you want to know? Is there a real question?

Comment: If you have questions about programming using DirectX 9 you can probably just ask them directly and get answers.

Comment: ok if i want a mesh tutorial that doesn't use class it is impossible to find one that is free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a pretty extensive tutorial by Microsoft at MSDN.
[Check it out here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ee416804%28en-us,VS.85%29.aspx)

Or you can go to the [Direct X Development Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/default.aspx)